# How to get query string parameters using RequireJS

Tags: javascript, widget, requirejs, config, query-string

I am using `RequireJS` for a Javascript widget that I have been developing. I need to get query string parameters from the loaded script in `RequireJS`. Is there any clean way of doing that? 
Let's say following is my script tag:

```
<script src="requirejs/build/app.js?arg1=test&agr2=test2" type='text/javascript'></script>
```

I need to get arg1 and arg2 later when the `RequireJS` loads all the modules. 
More specifically I need them here:

```
    define(['jquerync', 'bootstrap', 'custommodule'],
        function ($, bootstrap, custommodule) {
       //need them here in order to send server-side call for data    
    });
```

Why I want this? Sometimes the user create two widgets and then add the script of both widgets on the same page then I need to identify which script is being called in order to provide that script some basic initialization data about the widget to be loaded.
Or anyone have any better approach to tackle this issue?

Note: `Document.currentScript` is not an option as `RequireJS` loads files asynchronously plus its not supported in `IE`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  urlArgs in config if you want to append to requirejs.

```
 var arg1 = "test";
    require.config({
        baseUrl: "/scripts",
        paths: {
            "jquery": "jquery-2.2.1",
            "bootstrap": "jquery.bootstrap"
        },
        urlArgs: "arg1=" +  arg1
});
```

you could use following module to get query string from any module in Requirejs

```
define([],
    function () {
        function getParameterByName(name, url) {
            if (!url) {
                url = window.location.href;
            }
            name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
            var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
                results = regex.exec(url);
            if (!results) return null;
            if (!results[2]) return '';
            return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }

        return{
            getParameterByName: function (name, url) {
                return getParameterByName(name,url);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: window.location.href will return the URL of current window open (in the browser) which will be different from the js file url.